# how to join all elements in a list by using .join in every row in a particular column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4],'features':[["A","B","C"],["A","D","E"],["C","D","F"]]})
```

I tried doing below code snippet  but I am getting:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found`

```
train["some"]=train["features"].map(lambda x: " ".join([i.split(" ") for i in x]))
```

when I googled it I saw an answer and I understood that it happens if `x` in my case is lists of lists but it is clearly not in my case. I know the answer but I need an explanation why my code is wrong

Comment: In order to tell you why your code is wrong, we need to know what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[i.split(" ") for i in x]` Should produce a list of lists and assumes that there are spaces in each `i` element of `x` to split on.

`" ".join([i.split(" ") for i in x])` will join the list with `' '`... However, the list is of lists and you can't join `['a'] + ' ' + ['b']`... that makes no sense.  That's why you get the error.  `join` was expecting a string to perform a string concatenation with, but instead it found a `list` and did not know what to do.

After that, I have no idea what you are trying to do with the `lambda`.  Looks like you are trying to `join` a list and `split` it again... /shrug.

If I focus on the title of your question

```
train.assign(some=train.features.map(' '.join))

    features  id   some
0  [A, B, C]   1  A B C
1  [A, D, E]   2  A D E
2  [C, D, F]   4  C D F
```

Comment: `x` is a list.  `i.split(' ')` is a list.  `[i.split(' ') for i in ['A', 'B', 'C']]` is `[['A'], ['B'], ['C']]` which is a list of lists.